# NHibernate - Working with dynamic created Table

Tags: c#, oracle, dynamic, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-hql

I use Fluent NHibernate for project. Some database table created with SQL query dynamically. I execute sql select query as follow, but it return **-1**.

```
 var query = $"Select * from {tableName}";
 var obj = Session.CreateSQLQuery(query).ExecuteUpdate();// result is -1
```

> My question is how can I work easily with dynamic created tables in NHibernate - SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code would suffice.

```
var tableName = "YourTableName";
var query = $"Select * from " + tableName;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use .List method instead of .ExecuteUpdate

```
var query = $"Select * from {tableName}";
var obj = Session.CreateSQLQuery(query).List();
```

ExecuteUpdate method is only for UPDATE/DELETE. If you need to return some kind of results, you need to use List method instead.